# socket.io - getting more than one field for a socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code when a user disconnects. I want to emit a signal with the room name and user name.

```
client.get('nickname', function(err, name) {
  client.get('room', function(err2, room) {
    io.sockets.in(room).emit('disconnect', name);
  });
});
```

My question is, is there any way to avoid wrapping the `.get` calls like this? For my application, they are going to add up quickly. Can I get more than one value from one `get()` command? Or am I just handling this all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to get a lot of values, take a look at a flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/). For example, here's how you might `get` several values from the client in [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async/#parallel):

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel([
  client.get.bind(this, 'nickname'),
  client.get.bind(this, 'room'),
  client.get.bind(this, 'anotherValue')
], function(err, results) {
  // here, `err` is any error returned from any of the three calls to `get`,
  // and results is an array:
  //    results[0] is the value of 'nickname',
  //    results[1] is the value of 'room',
  //    results[2] is the value of 'anotherValue'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had all the attributes of a user in an object/array, and all the attributes of a room in an object/array, you'd still only need these 2 nested calls. You're doing it right.