# How to get multiple socket attributes in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a chat app on which, for every client connection, i need to set some attributes to every client instance using socket.io. When i save the attribute, i use:

```
client.set('name', name, function () {});
client.set('email', email, function () {});
....
```

and it runs fine. 
When i need to get all the client properties, i have not found a better way than this:

```
client.get("name",function(err,name) {
    client.get("email",function(err,email) {
       .......
    }
}
```

I need to nest all the "get" to asynchronously get data; but if i had 10 properties to get, do i need to nest all the 10 items? There must be a better way to do it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't attach attributes to the socket.

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var username = "xx";
  var email = "xx";

  socket.on('doX', function(data) {
    socket.emit('ackX', {username: username, email: email});
  });
});
```

I don't know if it's the best solution, but I have seen many examples like that.

EDIT : [socket.io - getting more than one field for a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405943/socket-io-getting-more-than-one-field-for-a-socket)
The correct answer may fit your needs

Comment: In simple setups, you solution works just fine, but the reason for `.set()` being async is that the data can be stored in, for instance, a Redis store and retrieved from other `socket.io` servers in a cluster.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. Is `require('async').parallel()` a good solution ? ( from my link ).

Comment: Yes, `async` is a great module for coordinating multiple asynchronous calls :)

Comment: Thanks, your link gave me the answer.